# Android Log Output KINETO

Tags: logging

On my T mobile G2 there is always a lot of action in my Log output that has the tag KINETO these are the two most common things it puts in there:

```
ERROR/KINETO(9304): KLOG0C3- xmk_QueryOSQueue SDL Queue empty : WAIT_FOREVER 
ERROR/KINETO(9304): KLOG0A3- ibs_os_GetMsg: Timeout forever for UKCC qHnd 0x80c34e3c
```

but there are a lot of others that it does as well. I am wondering what these logs are related to, because they seem to be happening basically all of the time on my device. I did a google search for KINETO and got a bunch of results for Wifi Calling related stuff, which kind of makes sense. My phone came with a Wifi calling app on it. But I never use this app. My suspicion is that I am getting these messages in the log because the wifi calling app does not have access to the internet on my device because of DroidWall. But my question is why does it try so often? and does anyone know if there is a way to stop it from trying so much I am sure this behavior has some negative impact on my battery life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kineto is the company that makes the Wifi calling software that is present on some Tmobile phones such as the G2.  Unfortunately this software is poorly written.  To make matters worse it is only possible to stop or remove the software if you root your phone.  (More accurately it isn't your phone - it is tmobile's phone to do with as they please.)  Coincidentally I contacted Kineto support yesterday to complain.  If more people do that maybe it will get fixed.

- It constantly spews out log messages at the ERROR level every second or so, despite the messages not being errors
- You cannot stop the software (needs root) and the constant logging still happens even if you disable wifi calling
- Sometimes the software gets confused and you have to reboot the phone to get it working again
- They haven't structured it like most Android apps separating the user interface from the service

It looks to me like they had an existing codebase that they ported to Android hence its poor structure and operation.

Answer (score 1):

Carrier apps like WiFi Calling generally try to run constantly as a background service, and stay connected so that they're instantly available.  Beyond that, we can't be any more specific about why it runs all the time (you *might* get specific details from the carrier, but don't count on it).

If you don't use it and don't want it to drain your battery, remove it!  It's probably a system app, which means you need to be rooted to remove it; you can use an app like Titanium Backup to remove it easily.

Another option is to allow it to connect.  Presumably it will stop "spinning" and trying to connect if you just allow it to succeed, and use less battery.